# Can I pass a parameter by pickerDate vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vue-component, vuetify.js

My datepicker like this :

```
<v-date-picker v-model="date" scrollable :picker-date.sync="pickerDate">
```

The datepicker in loop

My script vue like this :

```
  data: () => ({
    date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
    pickerDate: null,
  }),
  watch: {
    pickerDate (val) {
      console.log(val) 
    },
  },
```

In every loop, there exist a parameter id and I want to pass parameter id

I try like this :

```
<v-date-picker v-model="date" scrollable :picker-date.sync="pickerDate(id)">
```

But there exist error :

```
Syntax Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

How can I solve this problem?

Reference : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers#date-pickers-react-to-displayed-month-year-change

Comment: `pickerDate` is not a function, but you're using it as one. What are you trying to do with the `id`?

Comment: @tony19 Yes of course

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass parameters in picker-date, but still you can pass in Vuetify datepicker [update:picker-date](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers) event
When you change the month in datepicker, it returns the value as 2019-10 if the selected month is October. If you change the month November then the value will be 2019-11 and id is what your passing on the iteration

```
      <v-date-picker
        v-model="date"
        class="mt-4"
        @update:picker-date="pickerUpdate($event, id)"
      ></v-date-picker>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    date: '2019-10-15',
    id: 5,
  }),
  methods: {
    pickerUpdate(val, id) {
      // you can read the val --> 2019-10 for october, id what you  are passing
      // when you iterate with multiple date picker, you can set id's 
      // write your async call here
       console.log('from picker update ' + val + '  id: ' + id );
    },
  },
})
```